# Ocultar resultados no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde, galera. Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho várias linhas e cada uma delas está protegida com uma senha diferente para a edição, cada qual correspondente a uma unidade da empresa.
Preciso que os valores sejam ocultos para quem não saiba a senha, por exemplo:

Quando o usuário abre a planilha todas as linhas estão bloqueadas e com os dados ocultos, então, no momento em que ele liberar seu intervalo, os dados seriam mostrados, mas somente da sua linha, aquela que ele tem a senha e não as demais.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Já tentei com as configurações de bloqueio e senha, já tentei com o truque do ";;;", mas nada. Será que tem como fazer um filtro avançado ou algo do tipo?

Não consegui através de funções e sou leigo em VBA.

Obrigado.

Comment: Tu tens algum link de como bloquear as linhas? nunca vi disso.

Comment: Cara, ainda não tenho, mas posso fazer um tutorial e postar o link aqui.

Comment: Nem te estressa quanto a isso, não precisa fazer... era só curiosidade mesmo

Comment: Você pelo menos ja começou a fazer algo no VBA?

Comment: Lucas, tae o link http://www.aprenderexcel.com.br/2015/tutoriais/colocando-senha-em-intervalos-especificos

Comment: dHEKU não consegui, sou totalmente leigo em VBA, manjo das funções e o que não é "programação", mas já esgotei as ideias e não consegui ainda.

Comment: Só seria possível alcançar o que você deseja se houvesse um evento (em VBA) no Excel que fosse disparado quando o usuário digitasse a senha. Nesse evento, a senha deveria ser disponibilizada em um dos parametros da chamada do evento. Dessa maneira, você testaria se essa senha é uma das que existe e mostraria a parte do Excel relativa ao usuário em questão. Tal evento não existe e, se existisse, seria um furo de segurança do Excel. Enfim, dessa maneira você não conseguirá resolver esse problema. O que você poderia tentar fazer é um sistema de autenticação seu, pelo próprio VBA.

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer em minha resposta usei este mesmo método de bloquear cada linha, só que com código pelo vba. mas para ocultar/ reexibir cada linha inserindo senhas, fiz um link com botoes de controle. (Ver Respostas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Maximiliano Eu fiz uma planilha deste tipo.

Em uma nova planilha abra o vba (Alt + F11)
E clique em "Esta pasta de trabalho"
[image: Passo1]

Então cole o seguinte código, este irá garantir que toda vez que a planilha for aberta, nenhuma linha estará visível e toda a planilha estará protegida:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Plan1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
Range("2:2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Range("3:3").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End Sub
```

Depois clique em Plan1(Plan1) 
[image: Passo2]

E cole o seguinte codigo (Aqui estou inserindo proteção para duas linhas apenas):

```
Option Explicit
Sub verify1()

Dim senha1 As Single

On Error Resume Next

    senha1 = InputBox(Prompt:="Digite a Senha:")

    If senha1 = "111" Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"

    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Intervalo2", Range:=Rows _
        ("3:3"), Password:="222"
    Range("2:2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Range("3:3").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    Else
    MsgBox "A Senha Incorreta!"
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
Sub verify2()

    Dim senha2 As Single

    On Error Resume Next

    senha2 = InputBox(Prompt:="Digite a Senha:")

    If senha2 = "222" Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"

    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Intervalo1", Range:=Rows _
        ("2:2"), Password:="111"
    Range("3:3").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("2:2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

    Else
    MsgBox "A Senha Incorreta!"
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
Sub PlanProtect()
On Error Resume Next
Range("3:3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"

    Columns("H:H").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Range("A1:G1").Select
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        Selection.Merge

    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Intervalo1", Range:=Rows _
        ("2:2"), Password:="111"

    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Intervalo2", Range:=Rows _
        ("3:3"), Password:="222"



    Sheets("Plan1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True



End Sub
```

Agora na planilha "Plan1" Voce vai na aba desenvolvedor, na opção Inserir. insira Dois botões de seleção Controle de formulário) e renomeá-los, uma para "User1" e outra para "User2".

[image: Passo3]

[image: Passo3.1]

Depois de inserir os botoes, clique com o botão direito e atribua uma macro pra cada um, Macro Verify1() para user1 e macro verify2() para user2.

[image: Passo3.2]

Agora você volta para o vba em plan1 e clique na área da macro PlanProtect e clique em F5 para executa-la (Voce Tambem pode fazer isso direto pela planilha na opção Desenvolvedor > Macro)

[image: Passo 4]

Pronto! voce terá duas opções de linhas bloqueadas com senha.

> Se voce quiser mais, terá que seguir a "receita de bolo" que está no
>   vba. Fazendo copiou colou para cada linha que desejar e cada opção de usuário.
>   É bom também que você já tenha todos os dados na planilha antes pois depois pode ficar chato quer inserir informações com as planilhas bloqueadas
>
> **Observação:** Toda vez que a planilha for aberta, não mostrar nehuma linha a não ser a primeira, onde voce deve deixa-lá bem larga (Altura
>
> > 30 ou mais) para inserir os botões. se o usuario digitar a senha
> >     errada uma mensagem será mostrada como "senha Incorreta!" e não poderá
> >     ver a celula em questão.
>
> **VBA** 
>   Depois de ter a planilha pronta, vá no vba na opção Ferramentas > Propriedades do VBA Project. Insira uma senha de
>   proteção, pois um usuario expertinho pode querer ver o codigo e
>   consequentemente as senhas